# Using a templated function parameter type name to call a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I am using a C API that defines some functions for different types. Something like:

```
// defined in a header:
extern "C" A* A_create();
extern "C" B* B_create();
```

Is it possible to call these functions from a templated C++ function such that the template type parameter determines the C function to call?

Something like:

```
// Template specialization for when T_create() exists
template <typename T>
auto create() -> declval( T##_create() ) {

    // This is not valid syntax, but I'd like to call A_create() if this
    // template is instantiated with A, B_create() if this is
    // instantiated with B, etc. If the function doesn't exist, I'd like
    // the compiler to fall back to the generic implementation below.
    return T##_create() 
}

// Template specialization for when T_create() doesn't exist
template <typename T>
T* create() { 
    return new T; // generic version just calls new. 
}
```

Just wondering if its possible to do this without making explicit specializations of the `create()` function for each type coming from the C api.

Comment: Not a template, but maybe you can have a `std::map` from typeid to the functions.

Comment: Only a `#define` macro can create identifiers from smaller pieces.

Comment: You can't just mix `delete` and `free` so you need to keep track of if the generic `new` version was used or if it really was one of the C functions that `malloc`ed it so you know how to release the memory later.

Comment: The issue @TedLyngmo pointed out could be fixed by having the C-language wrapper specializations `return std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A*)>(A_create(), &A_destroy);` or similar, and the default template just `return std::make_unique<T>();`. Of course, code using them might need to add some `.get()` syntax in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no parameter to use, I would probably just use a function with specializations:

```
// generic version just calls new. 
template<class T>
T* create() { return new T;}
template<>
A* create() {return A_create();}
template<>
B* create() {return B_create();}
```

[Then usage should be trivial](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77d5e0fa61455ec3):

```
A* ptr = create<A>();
```

---

You can't avoid the specializations, but you can make them easy.

```
#define make_lib_create(T) template<> \
T* create() {return T##_create();}
make_lib_create(A);
make_lib_create(B);
```

Comment: This may be one of the rare cases when function template explicit specialization (and not overloads) is the answer. No need for structs.

Comment: @aschepler I momentarily forgot that complete function specialization was allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template the accepts a callable as a parameter. The following example provides 2 examples of how the `create` function could be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A()\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "B()\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()\n"; }
};

std::unique_ptr<A> create_A()
{
    return std::make_unique<A>();
}

std::unique_ptr<B> create_B()
{
    return std::make_unique<B>();
}

template<typename C>
auto create(C createFn)
{
    return createFn();
}

template<typename T>
auto create2(T (*createFn)())
{
    return createFn();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "create()\n";
    {
        auto a = create(&create_A);
        auto b = create(&create_B);
    }
    
    std::cout << "create2()\n";
    {
        auto a = create2(&create_A);
        auto b = create2(&create_B);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
create()
A()
B()
~B()
~A()
create2()
A()
B()
~B()
~A()
```